# How to create a random .txt(Human readable text like ascii) file in linux

Tags: linux

I need to create a text file which should contain random text data that can be read by human. I know that we can use `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random` for getting random data. But it is not readable by humans. I need to create a file which contains random text format. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: "Readable by humans" as in making actual sense? Full sentences? Or just some dictionary words?

Comment: Depending on the definition of "random" and what you're trying to accomplish, there are a number of Lorem Ipsum generators available in, or accessible from, Linux, often downloadable from your distro's repository.  See [Is there something like a lorem ipsum generator?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97160/85417), [Offline lorem ipsum generator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/94747/6278788), https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/lorem-ipsum-generator/, etc.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

We can do it by following command

```
base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 10000000 > file.txt
```

It creates a file with name file.txt size of 10 MB.

Comment: This great, it also adds a newline every 76 characters too.

Comment: use the `-w 0` flag to `base64` if you do NOT want those newlines. This will put everything on one line

Comment: `head -c 10485760` to get exactly 10MB

Answer (score 17):

get the output of:

```
tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom
```

and pipe it to a file.

You can use *head* command with -c or -n to limit the file size

example to generate a 1kB file a.txt:

```
tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 1024 > a.txt
```

Comment: You can also use `[:alnum:]` instead of `A-Za-z0-9`. Also, if you want spaces and newlines sprinkled in, you can do this variation: `tr -dc '[:alnum:] \n' ...`

Answer (score 6):

The `wamerican` package provides a dictionary of words available under `/usr/share/dict/words`.

You can use the following trick to use these:

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words | sort -R | head -1024 > file.txt
```

Note that you don't specify the geometry (how many words per line, how many lines?)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have /dev/urandom (because maybe you're using a GitBash console), you can use:

```
openssl rand 33000 -base64 -out dump.txt
```

Comment: just to highlight that openssl will generate an encrypted file

Answer (score 4):

`base64` seems to only output alphanumeric characters plus `/` and `+`.

I like this to get more "punctuation" characters, like

```
'[:punct:]'
  Punctuation characters; in the 'C' locale and ASCII character
  encoding, this is ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \
  ] ^ _ ` { | } ~
```

So use this:

```
'[:graph:]'
     Graphical characters: '[:alnum:]' and '[:punct:]'
```

and use `tr` to remove single quotes ' backticks ` and backslashes \

```
tr -dc '[:graph:]' < /dev/urandom | tr -d \''\\'\` | head -c [size]
```

the `-c` size option to `head` can  have  a multiplier suffix: b 512, kB 1000, K 1024, MB 1000*1000, M 1024*1024, GB
       1000*1000*1000, G 1024*1024*1024, and so on for T, P, E, Z, Y.

Answer (score 3):

improved version of the suggestion from Clement (above):

```
shuf -n 100 /usr/share/dict/words | fmt -w 72
```

adjust the "-n" and "-w" arguments for total number of words and line length, respectively.

this version eliminates the excessive number of proper nouns and possessives in the word list:

```
(sed -e "/^[A-Z]/d" -e "/'s\$/d" | shuf -n 100 | fmt -w 72) </usr/share/dict/words
```