# How to create multiple random human readable txt files within a certain range of files sizes? Linux

Tags: linux, unix

Based on [this previous post](https://superuser.com/questions/692175/how-to-create-a-random-txthuman-readable-text-like-ascii-file-in-linux),  I was able to generate a single human readable txt file of certain size.

```
base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 26211000  > file1.txt
base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 32211000  > file2.txt
```

I would like to able to generate 5000 human readable text files. I would like for the files to between 25mb and 28mb in size.

What do i need to do generate these files?

Answer (score 2):

That's very simple:

```
for num in $(seq 1 5000); do
  base64 /dev/urandom | head -c $(shuf -i 26214400-29360128 -n 1)  > file${num}.txt; 
done
```

The range defined in `shuf` is inclusive, by the way.